# Failed to invoke javascript, $ is undefined

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

i failed to pass the value to my script, anyone can tell me what is my mistake ?

**output**

Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

**my javascript function**

```
function setSessionValue(key, value) {

    $.post('setSession.aspx?key=' + key + '&value=' + value);        
}
```

**button to call for function**

```
asp:LinkButton ID="lnkname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("movieTitle") %>' Width='500px'
CommandName="cmdLink" PostBackUrl='~/videotest.aspx'` 
OnClientClick="setSessionValue('itemID','3345');"
```

Comment: i am sorry i didnt import it yet,thanks for telling me =)

Comment: @CheemunLow, you need to accept the answer for your question. Please read the FAQ section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you included jquery js files in your page?

```
<script 
     type="text/javascript"          
     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

include jquery library in your asp page

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason would be,

1. You have **forgot to import** the jQuery library or it is **failing to download** at client machine.
2. You have used **`$` syntax before importing** the jQuery.

The syntax should look like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="SOURCE OF YOUR JQUERY.JS FILE">
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function setSessionValue(key, value) {
          $.post('setSession.aspx?key=' + key + '&value=' + value);        
     }
 </script>
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you have imported jquery first before any scripts using it.